# autofilter with criteria1:=* returns all alphabetical cells

Tags: vba

When I use `AutoFilter` function with `Criteria1:="*"`, it returns all alphabetical cells instead of just cells of value `"*"`.

Suppose in column 1 the possible values are `"*", "Apple", "Tomato", "167", "55"`. The following code returns rows containing `"*", "Apple" and "Tomato"` instead of just `"*"`.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$U$1291").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*"
```

Comment: `Criteria1:="~*"`

Comment: The asterisk is a text wildcard :) so do as @ScottCraner suggests to ensure it's properly escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comments of Scott and David:

the asterisk character (*) is what you call a wildcard and it functions as a comparison critera (or *fuzzy* logic criteria if you prefer that term).

So in essence by writing `Criteria1:="*"` you're telling excel that your search criteria is any character. An example from the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb):

`criteria1:="*east"` will show `northeast`,`southeast` or anything containing `east`.

To escape it you use the tilde `~` followed by your wildcard character, i.e.  `"~*"`

Examples

`"*cake"` returns  `cake`

`"~*cake"` returns `*cake`

`"c?ke"` returns `c(any character)ke`

`"c~?ke"` returns `c?ke`